# What is the name of this Middle English letter?

Tags: etymology

The meaning of the depicted letter, in my opinion, is "and", but what is [its (page 61)](https://www.originalbibles.com/wycliffe-bible-new-testament-1400-pdf/) [Mk.1:15](https://old.bibleonline.ru/bible/eng/41/01/#15) name?

[image]

Comment: I think it's a form of [ampersand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampersand)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an ampersand, which nowadays looks like `&`. The version in this text is a combination of `E` and `t`, because the Latin word for "and" is *et*.

> & ſaide, þat þe tyme is fulfillid
>   & þe kyngdome of god ſthal come
>   nyȝ, do ȝe penance; & bileue ȝe to
>   þe goſpel, and as he paſſide biſi
>   des þe ſee of galile, he ſaye ſym

In modern spelling:

> and said, that the time is fulfilled,
>   and the kingdom of God shall come
>   nigh, do ye penance; and believe ye to
>   the Gospel, and as he passed besi-
>   -de the Sea of Galilee, he saw Sim-

I'm pretty sure the *y* in the second-last word is an outright error; it should be a *u*. Similarly, *shall* shouldn't have a *t* in it, even in Wycliffe's time: if anything that should be a *c*.

Comment: It seems to me that on the screenshot depicted the word ſthal in ſhal stead

Comment: @IwantToKnow typo fixed

Comment: @IwantToKnow I don't suppose it's "ſthal". It's much more likely to be "ſchal", as a reflex of OE "sċeal"

Comment: @Wilson it is highly likely